# VBA/Excel - Matching Column values with pre-defined sets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a case where I have a pre-defined set of values/codes what in a combination make some message. I also have an incoming file that I have to analyze on the codes, compare the sets against predefined values. The problem is that the incoming file doesn't exactly match my library:

[image]

In my library I have set of 4 columns and each row has it's unique meaning. I want to get that meaning as a string to further proceed with calculations. The problem is that the incoming file is not consistent. It doesn't follow exact sequence as in pre-defined file.

I need to compare them regardless of sequence. After being matched I want to grab corresponding Meaning from Library and proceed working with Case in my file.

Any ideas how to implement it in VBA?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to match on distinct sets. In other words, `SOME CASE 3` should match to `SOME MEANING 6`, because they share the same unique set of values (`ERTY`, `FGHJ`, `GFOP`). Is this correct?

Comment: @ZevSpitz That's exactly what I'm trying to do :) The thing is that GFOP can be in the third column or in the fourth as for ex. Case 2, or can be exactly the same as Meaning 6 (which would be simple).

Comment: If you have Excel 2016 or later, with the TEXTJOIN function, you can do this with worksheet functions. Or you could use these worksheet functions in a vba function to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offhand, you could create a VBA function that would return a string representing [the unique values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32618636/111794).

If there is some character that will never be in the values, you could delimit the values with that character (such as `_`):

```
Function GetUniqueValuesString(rng As Range) As String
    Dim rngValues() As Variant
    rngValues = rng.Value

    ' The following line requires a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    ' (via Tools -> References...)
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary

    'The function only parses the first row of the range
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To UBound(rngValues, 2)
        dict(rngValues(1, i)) = 1 ' 1 here is a dummy value
    Next

    GetUniqueValuesString = Join(dict.Keys, "_")
End Function
```

(If every value is always the same number of characters, you could simply join them, without any delimiter.)

Using this function against a horizontal cell range:

```
=GetUniqeValuesString(A4:D4)
```

should return a string with only the unique values:

```
BGAA_TGHJ_WETY
```

If you apply this function to both the library rows and the file rows, you should be able to match on the function's returned value.

---

Note that the function has a few limitations that might need to be resolved:

- It assumes the order of the values will be the same. In other words, `BGAA`, `TGHJ`, `WETY` will resolve to a different string than  `BGAA`, `WETY`, `TGHJ`.
- The function only joins the first row; other rows are ignored.

Comment: Sorry for missing that info out, the strings will always contain only four characters.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out and let you know how it went :)

Comment: it gave me an error with code 13 on the last line, says type mismatch: Join(temp, "_"). Where does this temp come from?

Comment: @mrGott Sorry! Updated.